# pass parameter in function

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

I want to pass string and integer parameters through a javascript function, but the integer passes as string.

The variable `attachfile` is a string.

```
var upload_number = 1;

input.setAttribute("onClick", "removeBtn(attachfile+ upload_number)");
```

Comment: User parseInt javascript function http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: remove.setAttribute("onClick", removeBtn('parseInt(upload_number)')'); it also does nothing what i did wrong in this code?

Comment: The code in your comment has mismatched quotation marks, so it wouldn't work at all. Also it has quotation marks around `parseInt(...)` so that means it passes a string with the actual letters p, a, r, etc., it doesn't call the `parseInt()` function. If you want to just pass the number as the only parameter you don't need `parseInt()`, just say `remove.setAttribute("onClick", "removeBtn(upload_number)");`.

Comment: ooooooh thanx, how i will upvote ur comment and thanx again for ur effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you showed the declaration for your `removeBtn()` function, but the problem seems to be that you are not passing two parameters to the function, you are passing one parameter that takes the value of `attachfile` concatenated with `upload_number` - and when you concatenate a string with a number the result is a string.

You need to pass the parameters separately, i.e., instead of:

```
removeBtn(attachfile+ upload_number)
```

Use:

```
removeBtn(attachfile, upload_number)
```

Then the declaration of `removeBtn()` should be:

```
function removeBtn(theFile, theNumber) { // name the parameters however you like
```

(By the way, the way you are setting the `onclick` attribute to a string that contains a function call may also be causing you some problems because (amongst other issues) that function and the parameters would need to be globals. But that's - possibly - outside the scope of this question, at least unless you update it to show more of your code.)

Comment: sry, u r right i want to pass one parameter a string concatenated with integer

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do. If you _want_ a a string concatenated with an integer to pass as a single parameter then obviously that parameter is not going to end up as an integer, so what is the problem? Maybe you should show your `removeBtn()` function so that we can see how it tries to use the parameter...

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to convert that to a number or you can use `parseInt(your_variable,10)`

10 here is a radix

**EDIT**

I meant jquery to validate whether its a number

Comment: you don't require a third party library like jquery to do parseInt

Comment: How do you use jQuery to convert a string to a number? (And why would you?)

Comment: remove.setAttribute("onClick", removeBtn('parseInt(upload_number)')'); it also does nothing what i did wrong in this code?

Comment: Sorry i meant you can verify! not convert ! using the validations of jquery

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a `parseInt()` function. The `parseInt()` function parses a string and returns an integer.

The radix parameter is used to specify which numeral system to be used, for example, a radix of 16 (hexadecimal) indicates that the number in the string should be parsed from a hexadecimal number to a decimal number.

If the radix parameter is omitted, JavaScript assumes the following:

- If the string begins with "0x", the radix is 16 (hexadecimal) If the
- string begins with "0", the radix is 8 (octal). This feature is
- deprecated If the string begins with any other value, the radix is 10
  (decimal)

**Syntax:**

```
parseInt(string, radix)
```

(stolen from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp))